# Why does this get Method return a null value?

Tags: java, object, null, return-value, getmethod

I can not figure out why the return value for method `getButton` is null.

I am trying to create a maze game. The `setUp` method, in the `MazeFrame`, class draws the maze. Each step within the maze is a button which, in this program, is a `Step` object which extends `JButton`.

I need the `getButton` method to work, so I can call it in other classes and refer to a particular step/button by its index, but this method is bent on always returning null, instead of the correct button I am referring to.

The only time it does not return null is when I call it with a = 6, b = 6, which is the step.length - 1. Then it returns the correct button.

I tried creating an `ArrayList` where I stored each Step/Button as soon as they were created. Then I had the `getButton` method run through this array list and return the step within it that had the same index values (a and b, i and j, row and column) as the index values passed into `getButton`.

The return value is still null.

```java
public class MazeFrame extends JFrame {
    Container contentPane;
    private int buttonCount = 7;
    private Step[][] steps;
    private ArrayList<Step> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstMaze thisOne = new FirstMaze();
        thisOne.SetUp();
        thisOne.pack();
        thisOne.setVisible(true);
        thisOne.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    public void SetUp() {
        //sets up container and sets layout grid
        contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(buttonCount, buttonCount));

        //run through the grid
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttonCount; j++) {
                steps = new Step[buttonCount][buttonCount];

                //create and add buttons to the container
                //for the start button
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    contentPane.add(steps[i][j] = new Step(i, j, "start", this));
                }
                //for the goal button
                else if (i == buttonCount - 1 && j == buttonCount - 1) {
                    contentPane.add(steps[i][j] = new Step(i, j, "goal", this));
                }
                //every other button
                else {
                    contentPane.add(steps[i][j] = new Step(i, j, "intermediary", this));
                }
                steps[i][j].setTransitions(steps[i][j].getTransitions(i, j));
                getButton(i, j); //call to getButton
            }
        }
    }

    public Step getButton(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("is the step: a,b null? " + (steps[a][b] == null)); //Print statement is a test
        return steps[a][b];
    }
}
```

The print statement in `getButton` is a test, and it confirms that the return value is null.

Comment: Create and post your [mcve].

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so we can't really tell.   What guarantees that the initialization has been executed?  Where is that initialization code?  It must belong in some method, or the constructor, but you have not shown that part, which is crucial to the answer.

Comment: re: *when the return value is steps [4][4]*  There is no such thing. Both of the dimensions run from 0 to 3; index 4 would be off the end.  When a and b are both 4, you return steps[0][0].

Comment: Where is your code which *fills* this array located? Is it perhaps in some method? Are you sure that this method is being called *before* you try to read values from array? There are many scenarios which can cause this problem but to say for sure which is it we would need code which we can actually run so we could debug it. So to get proper answer please use [edit] option and provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE]).

Comment: Each iteration of your loop, you set `steps` to a **new empty array** and then set one element in it. This line should not be inside your loops: `steps = new Step[buttonCount][buttonCount];`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttonCount; j++) {
            steps = new Step[buttonCount][buttonCount];
            ...
```

In each iteration of your loop, you set steps to a new **empty** array and then set one element in it.

The `steps =` line should not be inside your loops. Move it to before:

```
    steps = new Step[buttonCount][buttonCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttonCount; j++) {
            ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Your for loop to initialize the array either needs to be placed in a constructor or enclosed in curly brackets to use it as an initialization block.

```
public class MyClass {
    // wrap the loop in curly brackets
    {
        for (...)
    }
    ...
}
```

If your code is within a static class, you need to mark your initialization block as static, too.

```
public static class MyClass {
    // wrap the loop in curly brackets
    static {
        for (...)
    }
    ...
}
```

Personally, I recommend putting this code in a constructor method.

Comment: While true, this is surely not an answer, because the code as presented by the OP simply won't compile.

Comment: "*If your code is within a static class, you need to mark your initialization block as static, too.*" that is simply not true (at least in Java). Static initialization block has different purpose than non-static initialization block and both are allowed in static classes (which must be nested inside some outer classes).